# How to set up LinqPad Using "dotPeek" instead of ".Net Reflector" when press "Shift + F1"?

Tags: linqpad

The LinqPad call ".Net Reflector" to get members decompile information when user press "Shift + F1".

".Net Reflector" is costly, it need $190. but "dotPeek" is free! So if anybody can give detail steps on How to set up LinqPad Using "dotPeek" instead of ".Net Reflector" when press "Shift + F1", will be great appreciate!

Comment: didnt know about this shortcut thanx+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, dotPeek has no automation support and doesn't accept command-line arguments. Therefore, it's impossible for other applications to control it. If you have any information to suggest otherwise, let me know and I'll look into it further.